# App opens in different ViewController on return to foreground

Tags: ios, swift

My IOS app has 2 navigation controllers in the same storyboard.

`EntryPoint -> FirstNavigationController -> AViewController -> BViewController -> CViewController -> ......`

if certain conditions are met in `BViewController`, i segue to a another NavigationController instead of continuing on to `CViewController`.

`BViewController -> NewNavigationController -> DViewController -> EViewController`

My problem is that if i switch to another app in `DViewController` when my app returns to the foreground, it firsts shows `DViewController` then immediately switches to `BViewController`

This only happens when i go down the new navigation controller path. If i switch apps in `CViewController`, when i return, it stays in `CViewController` as it should.

In `applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)` in appDelegate,

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.restorationIdentifier
```

prints the restorationIdentifier of `FirstNavigationController` so for some reason my rootViewController doesn't change when i change to another navigation controller. Should it? Am i missing something?

viewDidLoad(), viewWillAppear() and viewWillDisappear() of DViewController. They are pretty much empty.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.usernameTextField.delegate = self
    enableContinueButton()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //add notifications for keyboard
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    //remove notifications for keyboard
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Because you said it shows `DViewController` and then immediately switches to `BViewController`,  Show us what you have in `ViewWillAppear` or `ViewDidAppear` of `DViewController`

Comment: Why are you going to another navigation controller instead on just pushing DViewController on the current navigation stack?

Comment: @JacobVanBrunt the thought process is to replace the navigation stacks so that every view in the first navigation stack gets destroyed and the user is unable to go back to any view in that stack

Comment: @SandeepBhandari just did

Comment: @someguyfortune : Saw your update, quite strange issue :|

Comment: Rather than presenting a new navigation controller, if your desire is to prevent the user from going back, simply modify the `viewControllers` array of the first navigation controller so that the earlier VCs are removed